# Best practices to reduce file size?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, filesize

What are the best practices, in general to reduce the file size of your iphone app?

Comment: Finding out why its size is large at the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do Reuse of functions instead of multiple functions
2. Remove unnecessary code
3. Remove debugging code.
4. Use object oriented style of coding instead of procedural

See this links:
1. [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490910/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-my-iphone-application)
2. [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963400/how-can-i-reduce-the-size-of-wav-audio-files-for-iphone-apps)
3. [question3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998946/how-to-reduce-code-size-of-iphone-app)